# Query broken after spring boot upgrade from 2.6.x to 2.7.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Controller

```
      @RequestParam(value = "term", required = false) String term,
      @SortDefault(sort = X_.NAME, direction = Direction.ASC) Pageable pageable) {
    Page<SomeResult> results = findSome(..., pageable)
```

Repository

```
     @Query("""
      SELECT x FROM X x
      WHERE x.fieldId IN (:fieldIds)
          AND ((:statusList) IS NULL OR t.status IN (:statusList))
          AND (:term IS NULL OR LOWER(x.name) LIKE :term OR LOWER(x.code) LIKE :term)
          AND (:excludeId is NULL OR NOT EXISTS (
              FROM Y y
              WHERE y.id.someId = x.id
                AND y.id.someOtherId = :excludeId
              )
          )
       """)
  Page<X> findSome(
      Set<Long> fieldIds,
      List<Status> statusList,
      String term,
      Long excludeId,
      Pageable pageable);
```

Issue

```
ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker -  Invalid path: 'y.name'
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'pt.name' [SELECT x FROM com.package.X x
WHERE t.fieldId IN (:fieldIds)
    AND ((:statusList) IS NULL OR t.status IN (:statusList))
    AND (:term IS NULL OR LOWER(x.name) LIKE :term OR LOWER(x.code) LIKE :term)
    AND (:excludeId is NULL OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT y FROM com.package.Y y
        WHERE y.id.someId = x.id
          AND y.id.someOtherId = :excludeId
        )
    )
 order by y.name asc];
```

The pageable acts on the inner `FROM Y y...`. If i remove that part, it works as expected.

This doesn't happen on spring boot 2.6.3 from which i'm upgrading.
I'm using postgresql v14

Comment: Your sub query misses a `SELECT y.id`...

Comment: True, but that's not the problem. It works without it.

Comment: It **worked** without it. Upgrading Spring BOot also updates dependencies which are stricter. So I would fix it, you also don't state which database you are using nor does your error match the query).

Comment: @M.Deinum updated it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there were/are some issues with queries when they're part of a multi-lined java string block.

Check this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2563) in spring data jpa project

The workaround that i've found to make it work was to change the layout of the query from

```
     @Query("""
      SELECT x FROM X x
      WHERE x.fieldId IN (:fieldIds)
          AND ((:statusList) IS NULL OR t.status IN (:statusList))
          AND (:term IS NULL OR LOWER(x.name) LIKE :term OR LOWER(x.code) LIKE :term)
          AND (:excludeId is NULL OR NOT EXISTS (
              FROM Y y
              WHERE y.id.someId = x.id
                AND y.id.someOtherId = :excludeId
              )
          )
       """)
```

to

```
     @Query("""
      SELECT x FROM X x
      WHERE x.fieldId IN (:fieldIds)
          AND ((:statusList) IS NULL OR t.status IN (:statusList))
          AND (:term IS NULL OR LOWER(x.name) LIKE :term OR LOWER(x.code) LIKE :term)
          AND (:excludeId is NULL OR NOT EXISTS 
          ( FROM Y y WHERE y.id.someId = x.id AND 
           y.id.someOtherId = :excludeId)
          )
       """)
```